# Isn't Reflection just absorption and emission?

Tags: visible-light, reflection

How do mirrors work? How do the atoms in a mirror reflect photons. Does it absorb and reflect? As I understand it, after an atom absorbs a photon it is bound to release that same photon of the same energy. Is this correct?

Comment: *"Isn't Reflection just absorption and emission?... Is this correct?"* No, it is not correct. Reflection is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics)

Comment: At an atomic level there are other processes that can occur besides absorption and emission. For example, elastic scattering of light. Reflection is more akin to elastic scattering than it is to a combination of absorption followed by emission.